# Post to Facebook from Kiosk

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, .net-4.0, kiosk

I am writing a C#/WPF/.NET4 non-browser application for a public kiosk. I would like to post a simple text string on a person's wall from this touch screen after they enter their email and password. I've looked around at all sorts of sample code but seem to be missing the right piece. I would much rather NOT use a browser for this. If anyone could give me a gentle nudge in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a browser control to have them login. Facebook does not have a way to accept a user name and password to return an access token.  You will be required to use oAuth in the browser.

Comment: Thank you for responding!!  Ok, I will use C# to compile my text string then pass that to a browser control pointed at facebooks login html.  As this kiosk does not have a keyboard attached I would like to use the keyboard control I've built in C#/WPF to enter the email and password.  Then I need to catch the browser control and close it after the successfull post so the next person can start the experience.  Any ideas on some sample code to get me started?  Any additional help would be GREATLY appriciated!!

Comment: Sure try this: http://hmadrigal.wordpress.com/2011/12/26/customizable-on-screen-keyboard-osk-for-wpf-it-works-for-webbrowser-control/

Comment: Awesome!!  That may be just what I am looking for!!  Are you certain it still works under facebook's new security?

Comment: Hi, 

We have had an similar experience while we were implementing a kiosk. In out scenario we use the feed dialog API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) which lets the user (and the application) to post a message only once. 

If you're planning to use WebBrowser "Control of WPF", you will have to strive against the cookie sessions. We have had difficult times removing these cookies because they can be only disabled by Win32 calls (using DLL Imports) or by a server request). Once you have deleted the cookies and cache the next user can log in normally.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Facebook Graph API.  There is a lot of sample code written in PHP that should be easy to translate into C#.  As far as I know, all of the C# libraries are out of date. (Please edit if you know otherwise).

Comment: The very popular [Facebook C# SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk) is definitely not out of date. What made you think otherwise?

Comment: Have you seen any example C# code to tackle what I am looking to do?  Very simply: pass a string to a browser control to be posted as a status on the users FB page.  Then once the login is successfull close the browser control.

Comment: @offbysome the third hit for facebook c# goes here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395/ which points at the deprecated page https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk

Comment: That particular one was a joke that Facebook never once touched and was never adopted by the community. But yes it adds to confusion for new .net Facebook developers.